# How to assign and access data from a struct of arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, syntax, struct

I'm trying to create an array of type struct but I'm having some trouble assigning and accessing data from it once I've created it. I have a basic understanding of what things do in C, but I'm still very new.

Here is my declaration of the struct and array:

```
typedef struct search{ 
    char word[10];
};

struct search words[40];
```

The first time I need to use the array is when I need to store a string in the first element (from a command line argument). What is my mistake, syntactically and theoretically?

```
words[0] = *argv[count]; //It says I can't assign char to struct words
```

The next time I need to access it is inside a function. The first line is how I have called the function, and then I will post the function prototype and then the lines inside that are giving me trouble. Please let me know if I need to clarify that structure.

```
parseSearchWords(words); // function call


int parseSearchWords(struct search *word); // function prototype


word[0][0] = 'a';// THe lines giving me the errors
printf("%s\n", *word[0][0]);
```

Although I'm sure it's obvious what's wrong with the statement, the error is: subscripted value is neither array not pointer nor vector.

Thanks for the help, please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: Before you use arrays, write a *simpler* program with just one single variable of type `search` and make sure you understand how *that* works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct search { 
    char word[10];
};
```

defines a structure `search` that contains an array of `char`s of size 10 as a member. When you want to access the elements (`char`s) of this array, you need to explicitly access this member :

```
int parseSearchWords(struct search *word) {
    ...
    word[0][0] = 'a';
    printf("%s\n", *word[0][0]);
}
```

should be:

```
int parseSearchWords(struct search *s) {
    ...
    s[0].word[0] = 'a';
    printf("%s\n", s[0].word);
}
```

and copying `argv` should look more like this:

```
struct search words[40];
int i = 0;
for (; i < argc; ++i) {
    strncpy(words[i].word, *argv[i], 9);
    words[i].word[9] = '\0';
}
```

---

And in case you want to use `typedef`, then I suggest you using more meaningful name than `search` and written in UpperCamelCase:

```
typedef struct search{ 
    char word[10];
} Word;
```

then the prototype of `parseSearchWords` function might become:

```
int parseSearchWords(Word *words)
```

Comment: @Vayran: You're welcome :) See my edit, I realized that the pointer you send to `parseSearchWords` is an address of that `words` array you were filling with `argv` right? :) The way you access its elements should be a bit different :)

Answer (score 1):

> What is my mistake, syntactically and theoretically?
>
> searchWords[0] = *argv[count]; //It says I can't assign char to struct
>   words

you should copy the `argv[count]` string into the `searchWords[0]`. The `searchWords[0]` is an array and it's not a pointer so it could not point to the argv string. Please refer to the following link to see the difference pointer and array: [*(a++) is giving error but not *(a+1)?? where a is array name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16456197/a-is-giving-error-but-not-a1-where-a-is-array-name)

You could copy  `argv[count]` string into the `searchWords[0]` in this way:

```
strcpy(searchWords[0], argv[count]);
```

And I think you mean `words[0]` and not `searchWords[0]`. If the case you can not access to the first array in this way. it should be `words[0].word`. So the copy will be in this way

```
strcpy(words[0].word, argv[count]);
```